# WCF Http Bindings, Require SSL

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, binding

I have the following binding I'm using with my wsHttpBinding webservice.

```
<binding name="wsHttpConfig">
  <security>
    <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
  </security>
</binding>
```

The issue is that it allows for the client to connect using either Http or Https. I would like to require them to use SSL. I tried adding the following:

```
<system.web.extensions>
  <scripting>
    <webServices>
      <authenticationService enabled="true" 
         requireSSL = "true"/>
    </webServices>
  </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

But it had no effect; client could still connect with Http. I then tried checking the "Require SSL" in the IIS7 SSL Settings and had client certificates radio set to Accept. Now, when I try to view the service I am getting the error "Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https]."

Anyone know exactly how to fix this error? I have been googling for the last 3 hours trying 500 different combinations (not 500, but too many to list) and could not get anything to run.

Comment: Post your services section too please

Answer (score 3):

For anyone stumbling across this one from Google, Bing (Bingle, Yangle?) then take a look at a blog post a put together to help others trying to run a secure AuthenticationService in a test environment.

http://www.lukepuplett.com/2010/07/setting-up-wcf-over-ssl-on-iis-7x.html

And good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Have you read [this msdn post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e5ece9ec-e386-40d4-a6c7-df88eceaa690/problems-enabling-ssl-for-a-webservice-hosted-in-a-windows-service?forum=wcf)?

> You must either change
>
> binding="mexHttpBinding"
>
> to
>
> binding="mexHttpsBinding"
>
> or else add an http base address in addition to the https base address.  (Right now the metadata endpoint is trying to get hosted on http, rather than https, and there's no base address for that.)

- Have you correctly [configured your endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2006/february/learn-the-abcs-of-programming-windows-communication-foundation#S9)?
- Have you tried dynamically [configuring the base address](https://web.archive.org/web/20200221040714/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/dlanorok/archive/2007/07/18/Dynamic-Configuration-for-WCF-Service-Base-Address.aspx)?

Comment: Yup, this is one of the forums I went over a few times. Changing the mexHttpBinding to mexHttpsBinding has no effect.

Comment: How about adding the http/https base addresses?

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/dlanorok/archive/2007/07/18/Dynamic-Configuration-for-WCF-Service-Base-Address.aspx <- dynamically adding base address in code

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163647.aspx <- configuring endpoints in config (goto the "Configuring Service Endpoints" section)

Comment: Sorry for the delay in testing the new suggestions. I should get to them this weekend.